# ajax dropdown box when a variable exists

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call for the an dropdown box(dynamic)

- when the variable `$place` is available it will make an ajax call and populate 
  the dropdown box.

I am trying to pass the variable `$place` to `listplace.php` and encode it in json data and get the datalist values but not sure the encoded json file is correct

I just given a try and not sure below code works, please help.

Dropdown box

```
<select>
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
</select>
```

Ajax call

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] !='') {?>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {place: '<?= $place ?>'},
        url: 'listplace.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            var $el = $("#name");
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
        }
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

listplace.php

```
<?php
$sql = @mysql_query("select placename from employee where placename= '$place'");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the ajax response by console or alert?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @2by2 i m not pretty sure over my ajax call i doubt whether my ajax request makes populates in the drop down list.

Comment: if place is available, you want to make ajax call but you are sending department in your `data` shouldn't this be the place?

Comment: @2by2 i edited the department as place, i left it by mistake, could you please help on with an answer..

Comment: is there another dropdown with the id `id="name"` in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your AJAX call to the following.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] != '') { ?>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {place: '<?= $_GET['place'] ?>'},
            url: 'listplace.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.option.length) {
                    var $el = $("#name"); 
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                        $el.append($('<option>',
                            {
                                value: json.option[i],
                                text: json.option[i]
                            }));
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No data found!');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

And your PHP to

```
<?php
$place = $_POST['place'];
$sql = @mysqli_query($conn,"select placename from employee where placename= '$place'");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r['placename'];
}
if (count($rows)) {
    echo json_encode(['option'=> $rows]);
}else {
    echo json_encode(['option'=> false]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, a doubt should i change my dropdown box code with respect to id name?

Comment: you can use any select id, you like. depends on where you want the option to be appended.

Comment: so should i add <select id=name> in my dropdown code!

Answer (score 1):

```
var request;

// Abort request is previous doesnt end
if (request) {
  request.abort();
}

// Make request
request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'listplace.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  // One option is passed php into script
  data: {
    department: '<?= $place ?>'
  }
  // but I prefer this solution
  // html markup:
  // <div style='display:none;' data-place>YOUR_PLACE</div>
  // or hidden input, in final it doesnt matter...
  data: {
    department: $('[data-place]').text()
  }
});

request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
  // check response status
  // HTML Markup:
  // <select id='select'></select>
  var select = $('#select');
  select.empty();
  // add default option first one disabled, selected, etc.
  // data are rows in your situatios
  // append data to select with lodash for example
  // _.map(response.rows, function(row){...}
  // jQuery each
  // $.each(response.rows, function(index,row){...}
})

request.fail(function(){
  // do something
})

request.always(function(){
  // do something
})
```

in your .php is missing line

```
$place = $_POST['department'];
```

Comment: thanks... should i add any id to my dropdown box code

Comment: yes id is faster to find for jquery, if you want to separe part of your code to faster work with DOM for example

<div id="main">
<select id="my-select"></select>
</div>

var main = $('#main);
var select = main.find('#my-select');

will looking for your select only in div with id=#main which is faster and its separeted, i prefer use id on base HTML element like <main> <footer> <header> and data atribute to work with element in javascript its cleaner. Your layout (with id) separete DOM to lowest parts.